# Python saving adding a column

Tags: python

I am trying to save these elements of a matrix in a new column:

```
for i in range(len(NEG_00_04_p)-1):
    *NEG_00_04_p1* = (NEG_00_04_p['wap'][i+1] - NEG_00_04_p['wap'][i]) + NEG_00_04_p['wap'][i+1]
    print NEG_00_04_p1
```

for example: minha matrix NEG_00_04_p is something like
5 columns(index, from day, until day, product, wap)
and 15 rows of information and I would like to add results from what I have acquired inside the loop so my NEG_00_04_p1 would be a column of results that i  wanna write as a new column of NEG_00_04_p

Any tips about it!

PS: also this program is not working because NEG_00_04_p1 will only save one result :X and I wanna all the results from the loop

---

```
 index   datum_von   datum_bis produktname    wap  new col1  new col2
0       0  2017-10-05  2017-10-05   NEG_00_04   4.22      1.31      4.22
1      12  2017-10-06  2017-10-06   NEG_00_04   5.53     -1.05      6.84
2      24  2017-10-07  2017-10-07   NEG_00_04   4.48     10.00      3.43
3      36  2017-10-08  2017-10-08   NEG_00_04  14.48    -11.57      ---
4      48  2017-10-09  2017-10-09   NEG_00_04   2.91     -0.81      --
5      60  2017-10-10  2017-10-10   NEG_00_04   2.10      1.32      ---
6      72  2017-10-11  2017-10-11   NEG_00_04   3.42     18.27      --
7      84  2017-10-12  2017-10-12   NEG_00_04  21.69     -4.92      --
8      96  2017-10-13  2017-10-13   NEG_00_04  16.77     -4.47      ---
9     108  2017-10-14  2017-10-14   NEG_00_04  12.30      1.17      ---
10    120  2017-10-15  2017-10-15   NEG_00_04  13.47     -4.18      ---
11    132  2017-10-16  2017-10-16   NEG_00_04   9.29      1.40      ---
12    144  2017-10-17  2017-10-17   NEG_00_04  10.69     -1.11      ---
13    156  2017-10-18  2017-10-18   NEG_00_04   9.58     -1.62      ---
14    168  2017-10-19  2017-10-19   NEG_00_04   7.96     -0.14      ---
15    180  2017-10-20  2017-10-20   NEG_00_04   7.82       NaN      ---
```

Comment: How can we know what you want without your data or your expected output? You're bound to have a hard time getting answers like this.

Comment: Yes, it is true sorry. Now I have written in the last column what I wanna may this helps to be more clear

Comment: But I guess it doesnt help because of the formatting. But I wanna x2+(x2-x1) as a result in the last column

Comment: @MayEmanuel your first column name is misssing

Comment: @MayEmanuel Is the result newcol1 or newcol2? I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Yes, we are almost there because using only diff I can get the difference between each number but still need to sum with the result of x2. So I am looking for a way to do x2 + (x2-x1) but until now I have only a column made of (x2-x1) this is my new column but what I wanna is a coumn made of (x2-x1)+x2  @coldspeed